# FaceRecognizer.train doesn't finish execution even after hours of waiting

Tags: java, opencv, face-recognition, training-data

Hello I am trying to train a dataset of images for face-recognition using `FaceRecognizer` of openCV.

Snippet:

```
public static void recognize(String trainingDir, String imagePath)
    {
        Mat testImage = imread(imagePath, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

        File root = new File(trainingDir);

        FilenameFilter imgFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                name = name.toLowerCase();
                return name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".pgm") || name.endsWith(".png");
            }
        };

        File[] imageFiles = root.listFiles(imgFilter);

        MatVector images = new MatVector(imageFiles.length);

        Mat labels = new Mat(imageFiles.length, 1, CV_32SC1);
        IntBuffer labelsBuf = labels.createBuffer();

        int counter = 0;

        for (File image : imageFiles) {
            Mat img = imread(image.getAbsolutePath(), IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

            int label = Integer.parseInt(image.getName().split("\\-")[0]);

            images.put(counter, img);

            labelsBuf.put(counter, label);

            counter++;
        }
        
        //FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = FisherFaceRecognizer.create();
        FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = EigenFaceRecognizer.create();
        //FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = LBPHFaceRecognizer.create();

        faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);
        
        System.out.println("temp");

        IntPointer label = new IntPointer(1);
        DoublePointer confidence = new DoublePointer(1);
        faceRecognizer.predict(testImage, label, confidence);
        int predictedLabel = label.get(0);

        System.out.println("Predicted label: " + predictedLabel);
    }
```

If I use `LBPHFaceRecognizer` the `train` method usually finishes after few minutes and I get the predicted label (even though it's a mismatch).
However when I use `EigenFaceRecognizer` and `FisherFaceRecognizer`, even after hours of execution, the method `train` seems to never complete its execution, hence never getting the predicted label. Why would you think this happens?

Comment: How big is your training dataset?

Comment: Pretty big. At the moment, 13k photos.

Comment: how about you train that _once_ instead of for _every prediction_

Comment: Yes, sure, but in order to do this it needs to finish first! The issue is that .train doesn't seem to finish. Maybe I will try to wait for more than 3 hours?

Comment: try with 1/10 or 1/100 of the training set. observe training time. does it grow linearly, sublinearly, superlinearly? how does RAM usage behave? what size in bytes on storage is the dataset?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for the reply! I will try and let you know. I can tell you right now that the dataset size is  2GB.